# r: Choropleth with customized legend and permanent display of country names

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, legend, plotly, choropleth

The following code creates a Choropleth map according to hierarchial clustering (using `hclust()` and `cutree()`):

```
library(plotly)
library(cluster)

hc <- hclust(dist(df), method = "complete")
df$member <- cutree(hc, 5)

cluster.means = (as.data.frame(aggregate(df[,-1], list(cluster= df$member), mean)))[,-4]

g = list(
  scope = 'africa',
  showframe = T,
  showland = T,
  landcolor = toRGB("white")
)

plot_ly(df, z = member, type = 'choropleth', locations = Country,
              locationmode = 'country names', text = Country, hoverinfo = "text") %>% 
        layout(geo = g, title = "Energy markets in Africa")
```

Now I would like to change two things:

1. Permanent **display of the country names,** i.e. not only when hovering over the interactive chart in RStudio. I have tried to apply the answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32548781/plotly-choropleth-map-display-country-names) to mine, without success.
2. **A non-continous scale**. Ideally, I would like to have no scale at all BUT 5 boxes for one cluster each with following three characteristics:
   (1) The color of the box should be according to its respective color in the choropleth 
   (2) Each box should contain the number of countries assigned to it, i.e. to the respective cluster 
   (3) Each box should contain the respective cluster means for the two variables (X1, X2) which are contained in `cluster.means`

I have attached such an exemplary plot of what I have in mind (it doesnt have to look exactly the same - just to convey the idea).

[image: An exemplary choroplot containing only 2, instead of 5 boxes]

Any help, advice, tipp is highly appreciated!

(Scaled) data looks as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(Country = structure(1:50, .Label = c("Angola", 
"Benin", "Botswana", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cabo Verde", 
"Cameroon", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Comoros", "Congo", 
"Cote d'Ivoire", "Democratic Republic of Congo", "Djibouti", 
"Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Ethiopia", "Gabon", "Gambia", 
"Ghana", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Kenya", "Lesotho", "Liberia", 
"Madagascar", "Malawi", "Mali", "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mozambique", 
"Namibia", "Niger", "Nigeria", "Reunion", "Rwanda", "Sao Tome and Principe", 
"Senegal", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Somalia", "South Africa", 
"South Sudan", "Sudan", "Swaziland", "Tanzania", "Togo", "Uganda", 
"Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), class = "factor"), X1 = c(-0.18, -1.03, 
0.6, 1.55, 0.22, 0.26, 0.76, 2.15, -1.43, 0.99, 1.79, -0.39, 
1.73, 1.57, 1.11, -0.09, -1.49, -0.46, -0.48, -1.22, -0.78, -1.46, 
-1.22, 0.35, 0.45, 1.29, -1.37, -0.61, 0.92, -1.3, 0.42, -1.18, 
1.4, -0.83, 0.06, -0.76, -0.19, -0.37, -0.63, 0.64, 0.93, 0.33, 
-0.76, -0.21, -0.59, -0.41, -0.74, 0.39, -1.1, 1.35), X2 = c(-0.22, 
-0.42, 0.72, -0.59, -1.27, 0.64, -1.35, -1.4, -0.35, -1.43, 1.07, 
-0.01, -0.51, 0.11, 1.14, -0.89, 0.77, 1.45, -1.67, -0.83, 0.71, 
0.92, 1.63, 1.68, 0.23, -0.18, 0.07, 0.8, -0.02, 0.82, -0.72, 
-0.41, -0.26, 0.02, -1.68, 1.67, 0.18, 0.98, 1.45, 0.31, -1.23, 
-1.38, -0.63, 1.41, -0.12, 0, -1.3, -1.64, 0.21, 1.52)), .Names = c("Country", 
"X1", "X2"), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**"Ideally, I would like to have no scale at all"**: This is achieved by adding the argument `showscale=F` to `plot_ly()`.

**"Permanent display of the country names"**: This is done by adding a `scattergeo` plot layer, as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32548781/plotly-choropleth-map-display-country-names), with a minor difference.  Because your dataframe contains a column of country names, but not one of country codes, you need to add the argument `locationmode = 'country names'`

```
p <- plot_ly(df, z = member, type = 'choropleth', 
             locations = Country, locationmode = 'country names', 
             text = Country, hoverinfo = "text", 
             showscale=F, inherit =F) %>% 
     layout(geo = g, title = "Energy markets in Africa") %>%
     add_trace(type="scattergeo",
             locationmode = 'country names', locations = Country, 
             text = Country, mode="text", 
             textfont = list(color=rgb(1,0.5,0.3),  size =12))
```

You will need to try out various colour schemes to find one that effectively shows the clusters, while making the permanent country name labels visible in contrast.  There is probably little you can do about the fact that the permanent country name labels will overlap eachother when the map is zoomed out.  With extra effort, you could specify a lat-long position for each of the labels rather than relying on their default positions, and this may help improve the appearance of the map, by separating the labels better. I assume, though, that since you asked for permanent labels you are intending to only use the map at a suitable zoom where they appear ok.

**To add the text boxes** you describe, you can use annotation layouts (one annotation per cluster).  I show here how to add one with a purple border, and a 2nd turquoise one.  You will need to adjust this to the colour scheme you end up using.

```
box1 <- list(
  x = 0.3,
  y = 0.5,
  yanchor = "top",
  borderpad = 2,
  bordercolor = rgb(0.5,0.1,0.5),     # set this same as color of cluster 1
  borderwidth = 5,
  text = paste("1. Cluster,  ", 
               sum(df$member==1),     # number of countries in cluster
               " Countries<br>X1 = ", # use <br> for line breaks
               format(round(cluster.means[1,]$X1, 2), nsmall = 2), 
               "<br>X2 = ", 
               format(round(cluster.means[1,]$X2, 2), nsmall = 2)),
  align = "left",
  showarrow = F)

box2 <- list(
  x = 0.3,
  y = 0.4,
  yanchor = "top",
  borderpad = 2,
  bordercolor = rgb(0.1,0.5,0.5),
  borderwidth = 5,
  text = paste("2. Cluster,  ", 
               sum(df$member==2), 
               " Countries<br>X1 = ", 
               format(round(cluster.means[2,]$X1, 2), nsmall = 2), 
               "<br>X2 = ", 
               format(round(cluster.means[2,]$X2, 2), nsmall = 2)),
  align = "left",
  showarrow = F)

p %>% layout(annotations = list(box1, box2))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! thats great, thank you :-) I have one question: I am adding the other boxes and make each box's `y-value` 0.1 less than the above. In the end I join them all together like this `box = list(box1,box2,box3,box4,box5)` and assign `box` to `annotations`. But unfortunately the distance between the boxes is not always the same... why?

Comment: The default anchor for annotations is "automatic".  Unfortunately, this means plotly chooses to anchor each box to the x,y position differently, depending on which anchor point is closest to the given y coordinate.  The remedy is simple.  Add the line `yanchor = "top"` to each of the annotation lists.  I've edited the answer with this.

Comment: Also edited a misplaced parenthesis in the paste() statement (now corrected), and increased padding around text boxes to improve appearance.

Comment: ok, super, thanks! May I ask one more question: How can I adjust the size of the title font, i.e. "Energy Markets in Africa"?

Comment: Additional questions are best posted as new questions, rather than comments.  Otherwise they are not searchable or useful to other users looking for this information. You can probably find the answer in the [reference materials](https://plot.ly/r/reference). If you are still stuck after searching the documentation, other SO questions, and trying out some possible answers, then consider asking this as a new question.  If my answer was useful and solved your original question, then you may like to consider accepting and upvoting it. Thanks.